# Running e2e tests with NextJS/Jest/Playwright

Tags: javascript, jestjs, next.js

I'am trying to run e2e for NextJS inside Jest.

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const app = await createApplication({ dev: true });

    server = app.listen(PORT);
    browser = await chromium.launch();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
    await server.close();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await page.close();
  });
```

When running `yarn test` I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPage' of undefined
```

When this test does not start the NextJS application it runs successfully

Full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-sunset-tw7qn